# Swedish poste restante - which postcode and collection point?

Tags: sweden, mail

I am moving to Stockholm and need to use the poste restante service. The PostNord website says senders should put 'poste restante' in the address line, followed by the postcode and town.

It then says, 'To find out where you can retrieve your mail, check the postal codes in our pdf with a list of postal codes to places where Poste Restante can be used. In order to then get information about the nearest distribution point for your mail, you can go to Search for service point and enter the postal code for one of the locations where the service is available.'

The pdf seems to be just the main areas, so I then went to the search function, set the search to 'serviceställe' and put in the Stockholm postcode 101 10. This has provided me with a lot of service points. So...

1. Should I choose one of these service points and use their postcode?
2. The service points are different varieties, e.g. frimärksombud (stamp agent), postombud (mail agent) and företagscenter (business centre). Can I only collect from a postombud?
3. What if there are multiple possible collection points with the same postcode? How do I know which one my post will go to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use the service for the towns listed in that PDF and pick up the mail at the post office indicated under **Utlämning sker via** (Delivery at).

Comment: Thanks, so would I use postcode 101 10 (Stockholm) or 111 64 (the postcode for the post office at Klarabergsviadukten)?

Comment: @Mousentrude Postnord says to use 101 10 Stockholm.

Comment: @Mousentrude Use the Postnord search function only for things like opening hours